# What formulas are used to calculate sight adjustments in ArmA 2 ACE2 Mod?

Tags: arma-2

### The Question

A friend and I recently began sniping in ACE and we can't seem to work out a proper formula to calculate windage and elavation adjustments. We've tried the [One Shot One Kill](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thewreckingcrew.osok&hl=en) Android app, but it, unfortunately, only supports a few guns and rounds to 1/.5/.25 [MOAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_of_arc).

We've also worked out a method for calculating the adjustments ourselves, but it's proven inaccurate. Our current method is as follows:

To estimate elevation, the spotter paints the target with the range finder, relays the distance to sniper, and then he adjusts for elevation using the range tables built into ACE.

To estimate windage, we use the formula `Distance / Muzzle Velocity * Crosswind m/s = Windage MOAs` where the scope is adjusted opposite the direction of the wind. The spotter usually does this calculation as he's the only one equipped with a kestrel and range finder and, depending on the stability of the wind, the windage adjustmant may need to be predicted ahead of time or recalculated in order to pull off a precise shot.

So far this method has proven accurate at about 1000 meters. Usually we can aim center mass and hit the target within the first shot. Unfortunately, at greater distances (1500-2000 meters) this method has proven inaccurate as it fails to account for elevation.

My question now is, are there any better methods for calculating sight adjustments in ACE? We've watched the tutorials, read the wikis, and poured through threads, but we can't seem to find much on the subject at all that doesn't involve largely inaccurate/unacceptable guesswork.

### Notes

For the purposes of these missions, we have the following items at our disposal:

- Sniper may use any NATO sniper rifle as long as it has a mil-dot scope and we know the muzzle velocity value
- Kestrel (can be used to find crosswind and headwind in meters per second along with altitude)
- Range Finder
- Dagr (can be used in conjunction with the range finder to find elevation, target distance, and target elevation)
- Spotter Scope (seemingly useless as you can't lase the target with it to find range)

We have the following values at our disposal, but don't know if all are pertinent:

- Muzzle Velocity
- Elevation
- Target Elevation
- Target Distance
- CrossWind Speed m/s
- Headwind Speed m/s
- Tailwind Speed m/s
- Wind Angle (in increments of 30 degrees)
- Altitude

Comment: I simply applaud you for wanting to find this information out.  This is deep and if someone eventually answers this I will pick up the ACE mod myself.  Do we have any Recon troops in the house? haha